# Android emacs keyboard not popping up

Tags: android

I've installed f-droid emacs and i switch to messages buffer, but then the keyboard disappears and i can't get it back up since there is no keyboard icon on the corner.

I have in the Android settings that i want the keyboard to appear in the navigation bar and it usually shows, but sometimes not.

If i click on the file open menu button, i do get the keyboard back to open a new file

I guess the messages buffer is read only, so it removes the keyboard, but that's not exactly right;)